# Trouble with display Date of Birth on Display

Tags: java, performance

I've created my program to try to read my date of birth but after initialising my program, it just displays 0. Please help, I have imported java local date, period, and date

---

```java
public studentInfo(char gender, String subject1,String subject2)
    {
        this.gender=gender;
        this.subject1=subject1;
        this.subject2=subject2;
    }
    //accessor method
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
    
    public int getAge()
    {
        LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
        LocalDate birthDate = LocalDate.of(1996, 9, 8);
        age=Period.between(birthDate, today).getYears();
        return age;
    
    }
    
    
    //mutator method
    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
    
    public void setAge(int age)
    {
        this.age=age;
    }

    
    //Display Info
    public void displayInfo()
    {
        System.out.printf("Name:%s%n",name);
        System.out.println("Age:"+age);
        System.out.printf("Gender:%c%n",gender);
        System.out.printf("Subjects:%s,%s%n",subject1,subject2);
        Date date = new Date();
        System.out.println(date.toString());
    }
}


class NgLengPoh_Lab_1 
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
    
    studentInfo getInfo=new studentInfo('M',"CSIT121","CSIT128");

    getInfo.setName("Ng Leng Poh");
    getInfo.displayInfo();

    }//end of main constructor
}//end of class
```

Comment: Your explanation of the issue is not clear

Comment: The code snippet does not display whether you defined `age` field at all; the date of birth is some hardcoded value within method `getAge`; if you call `displayInfo` immediately after constructor, `age` is not initialized - you need to set it via setter or at least init it with a getter.

Answer (score 1):

The function, `getAge()` has to be called where you expect the age.

Replace `System.out.println("Age:"+age);` with `System.out.println("Age:" + getAge());`

By default, an `int` variable is initialized with `0` and that is what you are getting as you haven't initialized `age` with any value.

Comment: But he say, "try to read my date of birth", not speak about Age.

Comment: @MauricioKenny - you are right that the question is not clear because the title and description talk about different things.

Answer (score 1):

This is so because, the getter method for age is not being called anywhere in the program and the getter method consists the logic to calculate the age. Hence, it is returning the default value of int which is 0.

Inside displayInfo() try calling the getter method of age, instead of directly accessing the variable.

```
public void displayInfo()
    {
        System.out.printf("Name:%s%n",name);
        System.out.println("Age:"+getAge());
        System.out.printf("Gender:%c%n",gender);
        System.out.printf("Subjects:%s,%s%n",subject1,subject2);
        Date date = new Date();
        System.out.println(date.toString());
    }
```